# Destruct object with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to destruct object by passing params, but i can't achieve it the way i want. Param's are `string's`.

```js
function(param){
  const obj = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
  }
  
  const {[param], ...destructedObj} = obj; // where param === 'foo' || 'bar'
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you give an example of how this function would work?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think the OP is trying to choose a property name to pull out via destructuring, e.g., `{foo} = obj` but using `{[param]} = obj` to choose the variable name. I'm pretty sure this can't be done, since it would allow the creation of dynamically named local variables (which would have significant impact on optimizations that assume the set of variable in-scope for each closure don't change).

Comment: @apsillers yep thats what i ment, Thanks for answer; seems pretty logical actually, meh. Gonna try to find another way of doing that x)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use Object.keys to retrieve keys and then decide which key to use to selectively destruct the object at hand:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

const { [keys[0]]: x } = obj;

console.log(`${keys[0]}:${x}`);
```

But I'm not sure where you are going with this?